# C# SQLITE Unlock database

Tags: database, sqlite, locked

i update my code with this code:

```
<code>sql = "UPDATE tableelements SET myelement= '" + textBox1.Text + "' WHERE id = '" + TextBox4 + "'";
command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, connectiondb);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();</code>
```

when i executed he's work perfectely without any problem but when i try it again i get an error who say:

```
SQLite.SQLiteEXception(0x80004005): Database is locked
```

:( i dont know what ill do :(

help please

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue.  The community has been providing answers and I think the last one may help both of us.  I am going to try and confirm it tonight.  It involves 'using' blocks and the disposal of objects with unmanaged resources.  Please look here and see if it helps you. [my post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28871467/c-sharp-sqlite-database-being-left-locked-after-a-read)